# How to obtain "all DIVs in different lines" if "DIVs can't stay in only ONE line"

Tags: css, css-float

I have tried to find a solution in the last days but I have not been able to.

Situation: I got a text in a div (it is a question for a user) and some radiobuttons in different divs (the possible answers).

Example:

```
<div class="group">
 <div class="question">How old are you?</div>
 <div class="answergroup">
    <div class="answ"><radiobutton....></div>
    <div class="answ"><radiobutton....></div>
    <div class="answ"><radiobutton....></div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now I want a css that enables me to have:

- all in one row if it is possible (sum of width < parent's width)
- "question" in a line, "answergroup" in ONE other if possible (all answers in the second line)
- "question" in a line, each "answ" in a different line (NO two "answ" in a line) if needed (lines are: question, answ#1, answ#2, answ#3... and NEVER question,  **answ#1 & answ#2**, answ#3..

I know how to use css to have the 3 different solutions but **how can I apply them based on the actual width situation in the browser**?

I think a media query is not the solution; I need something 'aware' of the actual rendering of DIVs. Do I need a jQuery-based solution?

thanks
Cosimo

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS's media queries. Find out about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp